# How to do ping `whoami`.google.com in windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, ping

I want to ping a server with the input of the first command being the the subdomain for the ping command.

In a simple term (Linux way of doing the same thing).
 ***`` ping `whoami`.google.com ``***

Now I want the same thing in windows CMD. How can I do this?

Comment: is that a question about ping or about whoami?

Comment: It's a question about CMD scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to parse the `WhoAmI` from Windows in a `FOR /F` Loop then use the `FOR /F` Loop variable in a Ping Command as part of the `FOR /F` Loop's `DO` Clause.

**You can Dump this directly into CMD:**

```
FOR /F "Delims=\" %_ IN ('
  WhoAmI
') DO (
  Ping %_.Google.com
)
```

**Or as a single line (which is easier to re-run by hitting the UP arrow)**

```
FOR /F "Delims=\" %_ IN ('WhoAmI') DO ( Ping %_.Google.com )
```

Assuming your domain is "Contoso.com" the Result is you `ping Contoso.Google.com` If you domain is "Adventureworks.Contoso.com" you `ping AdventureWorks.Google.com`